# Multiple overlapped (css, grid) images to one composited image as jpeg/png or base64?

Tags: css, dom, grid, base64, overlap

There are 2 css columns grid with 3 overlapped images in each column.
There is not HTML5 and as follows there is no canvas element.

That is:

- 1st column - image13(top) is placed on image12 which is placed on image11(bottom);
- 2nd column - image23(top) is placed on image22 which is placed on image21(bottom).

All images except bottoms image11 and image21 are with transparent background.

Are there ways to save (export) these overlapped images to one single image, either simply image (jpg or png) or at least to Base64 string ?

The best is to get 1 (png/jpeg/Base64) image combined as an opened book:

```
left side:  image1 = image13 -> image12 -> image11;
right side: image2 = image23 -> image22 -> image21;
```

or get simply 2 separated (png/jpeg/Base64) images:

```
image1 = image13 -> image12 -> image11;
```

and

```
image2 = image23 -> image22 -> image21.
```

Document object model would be preferable. But other ways are under consideration.